# Android Firebase pass data recyclerview to recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to pass data RC_1 to RC_2. How can I do this(cat, info, orderid) RecyclerView to RecyclerView?[Examp.pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5iEW.png)

My firebase node is like as to picture.
[My firebase node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBzqL.png)

//RC_1 Struct

```
 public class Name_Struct {
        private String name;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    }
```

//RC_2 Struct

```
public class Detail_Struct {
    private String cat;
    private String info;
    private String orderid;

public String getCat() {
    return cat;
}
public void setCat(String cat) {
    this.cat = cat;
}
public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
public String getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}
public void setOrderid(String orderid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
}
```

RC_1 for;
//Myactivity_1

```
private void rc_1_get_name(){
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child(“Pro_”);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            mName.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snp : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Name_Struct names = snp.getValue(Name_Struct.class);
                for (DataSnapshot recipeSnapshot: snp.child(“basket”).getChildren()) {
                    mName.add(names);
                }
            }
            mName_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

RC_1 for;
//Myadapter_ 1

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

```
    final Name_Struct names = mName.get(position);
    holder.name_.setText(names.getName()));

holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RC_2.class);

???

mContext.startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

Comment: What exactly would like to pass to the second activity?

Comment: I want to pass data id_1 and id_2(cat,info,orderid) of Mike(name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, the "Pro_" node contains a name that has the value of "Mike". This means that you can map that node into an object of type `Name_Struct`. And you are doing that successfully. Under the same node, there is however another node called "Basket". That node is represented by a Map object, where the keys are represented by those IDs (ID_1, ID_2, etc) and the value by `Detail_Struct` objects. To be able to map the data under the "Basket" node, you have to add a new property in your `Name_Struct` class called `basket` like this:

```
public class Name_Struct implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private Map<String, Object> basket;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   @PropertyName("Basket")
   public Map<String, Object> getBasket() {
       return basket;
   }

   public void setBasket(Map<String, Object> basket) {
       this.basket = basket;
   }
}
```

Now to pass the data to the second activity, you have to add iterate the Map and create a `List<Detail_Struct>` that can be added to the Intent so it can be read in the second activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I'm observing the data. When I want to read the data in the second activity, I get the error "java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List". how can i fix it?
//first actv.(Send)
intent.putExtra("basket", (Serializable) names.getBasket())

//second actv.(Retrieve)
List< Name_Struct > thumbs=
        (List< Name_Struct >)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("basket") //Error line

Comment: You cannot cast a Map to a List. As said, you have to iterate through the Map, to get the needed data, and that data add it to a List<Detail_Struct>. This list can be then added to an adapter so it can be displayed in a RecyclerView.

Comment: In the second activity, I observed the data. Named_Struct basket=(Named_Struct)bundle.getSerializable("basket"); Log.d(basket); How can I add the data I observed to the adapter in the Second activity (List<Detail_Struct>).

mDetail_Struct.add(products.getBasket());//Error line

Comment: As I already said, [iterate the Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map), and get the desired data into a List<Detail_Struct>. Pass that list to the adapter and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience Alex. It was definitely helpful. I guess I'll have to open a new topic because I'm having trouble doing the last step(iterate the Map).